# Query only records that match specific substring - Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to query my visitors records from my visitors table that has the the **OS** substring of `bot`.

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 of 8 records listed here right now. I just want to grab those 3.

I tried look [in this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries). I didn't really find what I am looking to do there, unless I missed it.

```
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('os',substr('bot'))<----- NEED help here 
        ->get();
```

## Update

I believe my question is *not* a duplicate of [this proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with laravel, this is a pure sql one. The duplicate topic explains you how to  filter on a substring.

Comment: Laravel where() usally take in 3 arguemnts like this : `->where('os', '____', '%bot%')` The second arguments is not as flexible as pure SQL as you think.

Comment: When people look for the answer of this question, they should see this `->where('os', 'like', '%bot%')` as answer ... which is axactly what @Eddy answered.

Comment: And your claim that this question has not been asked in laravel context before is equally untrue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631486/laravel-query-model-if-values-contain-a-certain-string-taken-from-search-inpu

Comment: No, people need to **understand** how they can query a database and from there they can translate it to any ORM. If you knew how to do this query in sql, then you would not have had to ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with 'LIKE'

```
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->where('os', 'like', '%bot%') //<----- Match any word containing ...bot.. at any place
->get();
```

Using a variable

```
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->where('os', 'like', '%'. $bot .'%') //<----- Match the searched variable
->get();
```

Comment: Ohh really ? I didn't know how LIKE work ... Oh ok. I will give it a shot.

Comment: what is the oposite of LIKE ? If I want to check the negative case ..

Comment: Is there such thing is NOT LIKE ?

Comment: Yes. 'not like' would work.